# Checkbox checked with one button

Tags: jquery, checkbox

When I click the button the first time, I would like checkbox1 to be checked, but checkbox2 and checkbox3 uncheck, then when I click the button for the second time, checkbox2 is checked and checkbox1 & checkbox3 are uncheck, and lastly when I click the button for the third time, checkbox3 is checked and checkbox1 and checkbox2 are uncheck. and On fourth click it will again enable first input. And i use this script in notepad++, i hope your answer can work and please give me the jsfiddle. Please help me.. Thankyou

I've this, i need jquery script of this body:

`<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="A" />
 <input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="B" />
 <input type="checkbox" name="check3" value="C" /><br />
 <input type="button" value="Enable" name="button3" id="btn3">`

Comment: Done, where should I submit my answer?

Comment: What's the problem, what is keeping you from implementing this? Stack Overflow is not a place for placing an order and receiving a black box program.

Comment: did you ever tried this one without trying don't ask anything..

Comment: @YuliamChandra here:)

Comment: if you dont want to help dont comment please:)@rkrk

Comment: if you dont want to help dont comment please:) @EmilLundberg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var clicks = -1;
$('#btn3').click(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
  $('input[type="checkbox"][name="check' + (++clicks % 3 + 1) + '"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arnellebalane/kukfcdfk/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a closure as follows:

```
$('#btn3').click((function () {
  var count = 0;
  return function () {
    if (count >= 3) count = 0;
    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").prop("checked", false);
    $("input[type='checkbox']").eq(count++).prop("checked", true);
  }
})());
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5uwvb2sr/5/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var checked = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn3').click(function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            $('#check' + i).prop('checked', i == checked);
        }
        checked = (checked + 1) % 3;
    }) 
})
```

Here is my [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/gnhp7a0u/). Enjoy :)